What is the correct order of input, and how does it work precisely?
When I want to understand how to input data from the keyboard into a variable, I start by asking how cin and >> work in this context. What is the difference between them, and how are things organized between them and the input buffer?
I used to think that cin is responsible for pausing the program to send data to the input buffer, and that >> is responsible for taking the input from the buffer to the variable, considering the data type of the variable and the input.
But it turned out that cin doesn't store in the buffer, but reads from it and stores in the variable, and I learned that >> directs the input to the variable considering the type. I didn't fully understand the difference in their functions—who interacts with the buffer and who stores. More precisely, I don't have a clear picture of the data flow into the variable.

cin(& an object) is an identifier while >> is an operator(which can be overloaded). The class type of the former has overloaded the latter.

Write it as std::cin and perhaps it will become more clear what is going on. Hint: It is an object of class type. Here is the documentation std::cin

Also, usually understanding the effect and usage is enough. Many other things are implementation details.

You can type std::cin into your programm all day long but it won't do anything until you use the extraction operator (>>) or std::getline to read from it. Don't worry about "pausing" or "buffers".

"responsible for pausing the program to send data to the input buffer" -- This is an implementation detail. As far as I know, there is nothing mandating that cin wait for input to be available. Its behavior is implementation-defined, so it could in theory repeatedly stream a space character when there is nothing in the keyboard buffer. Don't sweat this level of detail unless you're writing your own implementation of an input biffer or of cin. It should be enough to know that std::cin >> x will attempt to store what is typed in x.

Since someone gave you a link to cin documentation, here's one for the operator: >>. It's a rough read, but an interesting tidbit is that this documentation does not mention "cin". Another tidbit that could be helpful: std::istream (the type of std::cin) is an alias for std::basic_istream<char> (a type for which this operator>>  is defined).
